# Freeswitch - executing Shell script and save output

Tags: xml, freeswitch, ivr, fusionpbx, dialplan

I am running FusionPBX  4.5.10 and Switch   1.10.1 (64bit) on Debian 9.

I am writing custom dialplan to excute sheel script using **system** application. 
when i write this code it runs fine

```
<action application="system" data="myapp.sh"/>
```

but as mentioned in https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+system url when I write dialplan `<action application="set" data="OUT=${system foo.sh}"/>`

it does not run.

What I want to is to save the output of the script in a variable and to use it in dialplan.

Please let me know if i am doing anything woring or any help which can help me to achive this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it should work

```
<action application="set" data="OUT=${system(myapp.sh)}"/>
```

make sure there is no space between "system" and the "(" opening bracket